# Discord Bot: VoiceChannel.connect() not returning properly?

Tags: python, events, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I wrote a simple discord bot a little over a year ago that plays a soundbyte when a user joins a voice channel.  It worked perfectly fine up until about a week ago. Nothing has changed, but I think I've identified what's happening.

1. User joins a voice channel, on_voice_state_update() is invoked.
2. The bot joins the voice channel.
3. The bot joining registers another call to on_voice_state_update().
4. That call returns after doing nothing.
5. No other events are processed.

When it was working, after joining the voice channel, the bot would play the User's chosen soundbyte and promptly leave.

It seems like the bot is able to establish a connection to the voice channel, but nothing after `voice_client = await after.channel.connect()` is being executed.

Here is my code for on_voice_state_udpate():

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    # Ignore voice state changes that don't involve changing channels.
    if before.channel == after.channel:
        return

    # Only do stuff if the user has a hook set up.
    member_id = str(member.id)
    if member_id in target_members:
        # Disconnect bot from any existing voice clients before joining the new one.
        for vc in bot.voice_clients:
            await vc.disconnect()

        # If user is disconnecting, after channel is None. Therefore, do nothing.
        if after.channel is None:
            return

        # Join the user's voice channel and play the sound.
        target_audio = target_members[member_id]
        voice_client = await after.channel.connect() # This line cases the new call to on_voice_state_update()
        voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(target_audio))

        # After playing the sound, disconnect after a short delay.
        while voice_client.is_playing():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await voice_client.disconnect()

    return
```

EDIT: Modified the question after more debugging. The bot successfully joins the channel, but does not play the soundbyte or leave.

Answer (score 0):

[discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member) has the attribute [bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User.bot) which returns a boolean whether or not the member is a bot. You can check for this in your code.

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    # Ignore if member is a bot
    if member.bot: 
        return
    # Rest of code
```

This way, if the user joining is a bot, it wont continue the code. This is also commonly used in an `on_message` event.

If you want it to not call only if it's your bot, you can check if the user is your bot by using [Client.user](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.user) which references your bot.

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    # Ignore if member is a your bot
    if member.id == bot.user.id: 
        return
    # Rest of code
```

Comment: That doesn't address the problem. The fact that `voice_client = await after.channel.connect()` causes another call to on_voice_state_update() at all is the problem. By the time that function is called for the bot, the original call for the user has already been scrapped.

Comment: Hey, just read your edit. Could you try printing something random after `voice_client = await after.channel.connect()`? If it does print, it is probably a problem with the audio track itself

Comment: I tried this, and unfortunately nothing printed. I think I did figure it out though! The server I built this for was running version 1.7.2 of discord.py. I tried it with the most recent version, and it worked!